# Spoken Language Identification

Tags: python, speech-recognition, spoken-language

````
```import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, GRU, CuDNNGRU, CuDNNLSTM
from keras import optimizers
import h5py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import load_model


def language_name(index):
    if index == 0:
        return "English"
    elif index == 1:
        return "Hindi"
    elif index == 2:
        return "Mandarin"

# ---------------------------BLOCK 1------------------------------------
# COMMENT/UNCOMMENT BELOW CODE BLOCK -
# Below code extracts mfcc features from the files provided into a dataset
codePath = './train/'
num_mfcc_features = 64

english_mfcc = np.array([]).reshape(0, num_mfcc_features)
for file in glob.glob(codePath + 'english/*.npy'):
    current_data = np.load(file).T
    english_mfcc = np.vstack((english_mfcc, current_data))

hindi_mfcc = np.array([]).reshape(0, num_mfcc_features)
for file in glob.glob(codePath + 'hindi/*.npy'):
    current_data = np.load(file).T
    hindi_mfcc = np.vstack((hindi_mfcc, current_data))

mandarin_mfcc = np.array([]).reshape(0, num_mfcc_features)
for file in glob.glob(codePath + 'mandarin/*.npy'):
    current_data = np.load(file).T
    mandarin_mfcc = np.vstack((mandarin_mfcc, current_data))

# Sequence length is 10 seconds
sequence_length = 1000
list_english_mfcc = []
num_english_sequence = int(np.floor(len(english_mfcc)/sequence_length))
for i in range(num_english_sequence):
    list_english_mfcc.append(english_mfcc[sequence_length*i:sequence_length*(i+1)])
list_english_mfcc = np.array(list_english_mfcc)
english_labels = np.full((num_english_sequence, 1000, 3), np.array([1, 0, 0]))

list_hindi_mfcc = []
num_hindi_sequence = int(np.floor(len(hindi_mfcc)/sequence_length))
for i in range(num_hindi_sequence):
    list_hindi_mfcc.append(hindi_mfcc[sequence_length*i:sequence_length*(i+1)])
list_hindi_mfcc = np.array(list_hindi_mfcc)
hindi_labels = np.full((num_hindi_sequence, 1000, 3), np.array([0, 1, 0]))

list_mandarin_mfcc = []
num_mandarin_sequence = int(np.floor(len(mandarin_mfcc)/sequence_length))
for i in range(num_mandarin_sequence):
    list_mandarin_mfcc.append(mandarin_mfcc[sequence_length*i:sequence_length*(i+1)])
list_mandarin_mfcc = np.array(list_mandarin_mfcc)
mandarin_labels = np.full((num_mandarin_sequence, 1000, 3), np.array([0, 0, 1]))

del english_mfcc
del hindi_mfcc
del mandarin_mfcc

total_sequence_length = num_english_sequence + num_hindi_sequence + num_mandarin_sequence
Y_train = np.vstack((english_labels, hindi_labels))
Y_train = np.vstack((Y_train, mandarin_labels))

X_train = np.vstack((list_english_mfcc, list_hindi_mfcc))
X_train = np.vstack((X_train, list_mandarin_mfcc))

del list_english_mfcc
del list_hindi_mfcc
del list_mandarin_mfcc

X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=0.2)

with h5py.File("mfcc_dataset.hdf5", 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset('X_train', data=X_train)
    hf.create_dataset('Y_train', data=Y_train)
    hf.create_dataset('X_val', data=X_val)
    hf.create_dataset('Y_val', data=Y_val)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------


# --------------------------BLOCK 2-------------------------------------
# Load MFCC Dataset created by the code in the previous steps
with h5py.File("mfcc_dataset.hdf5", 'r') as hf:
    X_train = hf['X_train'][:]
    Y_train = hf['Y_train'][:]
    X_val = hf['X_val'][:]
    Y_val = hf['Y_val'][:]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------


# ---------------------------BLOCK 3------------------------------------
# Setting up the model for training
DROPOUT = 0.3
RECURRENT_DROP_OUT = 0.2
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(decay=1e-4)
main_input = Input(shape=(sequence_length, 64), name='main_input')

# ### main_input = Input(shape=(None, 64), name='main_input')
# ### pred_gru = GRU(4, return_sequences=True, name='pred_gru')(main_input)
# ### rnn_output = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='rnn_output')(pred_gru)

layer1 = CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=True, name='layer1')(main_input)
layer2 = CuDNNLSTM(32, return_sequences=True, name='layer2')(layer1)
layer3 = Dense(100, activation='tanh', name='layer3')(layer2)
rnn_output = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='rnn_output')(layer3)

model = Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=rnn_output)
print('\nCompiling model...')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=75, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), shuffle=True, verbose=1)
model.save('sld.hdf5')
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# --------------------------BLOCK 4-------------------------------------
# Inference Mode Setup
streaming_input = Input(name='streaming_input', batch_shape=(1, 1, 64))
pred_layer1 = CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=True, name='layer1', stateful=True)(streaming_input)
pred_layer2 = CuDNNLSTM(32, return_sequences=True, name='layer2')(pred_layer1)
pred_layer3 = Dense(100, activation='tanh', name='layer3')(pred_layer2)
pred_output = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='rnn_output')(pred_layer3)
streaming_model = Model(inputs=streaming_input, outputs=pred_output)
streaming_model.load_weights('sld.hdf5')
# streaming_model.summary()
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# ---------------------------BLOCK 5------------------------------------
# Language Prediction for a random sequence from the validation data set
random_val_sample = np.random.randint(0, X_val.shape[0])
random_sequence_num = np.random.randint(0, len(X_val[random_val_sample]))
test_single = X_val[random_val_sample][random_sequence_num].reshape(1, 1, 64)
val_label = Y_val[random_val_sample][random_sequence_num]
true_label = language_name(np.argmax(val_label))
print("***********************")
print("True label is ", true_label)
single_test_pred_prob = streaming_model.predict(test_single)
pred_label = language_name(np.argmax(single_test_pred_prob))
print("Predicted label is ", pred_label)
print("***********************")
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# ---------------------------BLOCK 6------------------------------------
## COMMENT/UNCOMMENT BELOW
# Prediction for all sequences in the validation set - Takes very long to run
print("Predicting labels for all sequences - (Will take a lot of time)")
list_pred_labels = []
for i in range(X_val.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X_val.shape[1]):
        test = X_val[i][j].reshape(1, 1, 64)
        seq_predictions_prob = streaming_model.predict(test)
        predicted_language_index = np.argmax(seq_predictions_prob)
        list_pred_labels.append(predicted_language_index)
pred_english = list_pred_labels.count(0)
pred_hindi = list_pred_labels.count(1)
pred_mandarin = list_pred_labels.count(2)
print("Number of English labels = ", pred_english)
print("Number of Hindi labels = ", pred_hindi)
print("Number of Mandarin labels = ", pred_mandarin)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SKYLAND-2\Documents\nipunmanral SLR\language_identification.py", line 79, in <module>
    X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=0.2)
  File "C:\Users\SKYLAND-2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2417, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "C:\Users\SKYLAND-2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 378, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "C:\Users\SKYLAND-2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 332, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 0]```
````

hi, i am trying to run the code which belong to nipunmanral spoken language identification and i received this error. this is my first time learning machine learning, i am trying to learn spoken language identification which classify what type of language from an audio. i hope someone can share some tutorial or fix the error.

Comment: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 0] , the problem comes from the samples you give it

Comment: how do i resolve the issue?

Comment: you are by yourself on this, try to do some research, or try to understand why some of the files don't work (could be the extension? size of file? time lenght? etc) do some testing